# Django local site setup not working with styles.css and a .png file

Tags: css, django, static, png

I am trying to set up a Django site locally using a static folder. Everything is working except that i can not get the styles.css and mainlogo.png file to work. The styles.css file is located in /static/css/styles.css  and the  mainlogo.png file is in /static/img/mainlogo.png. This base.html file below is located in blog/templates/base.html 
Here is the base.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Sentdex HTML5 and Django Tutorial</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css" type = "text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport content = "width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">
    <header class="mainHead">
        <img src="/static/img/mainlogo.png" width="700" height="144">
        <nav><ul>
            <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href='/blog/latestnews/'>News</a></li>
            <li><a href='/blog/latestnews/'>Archive</a></li>

        </ul></nav>
    </header>

    <aside class="sideInfo">
        <article>
            <h3>Recent News</h3>
            {% for post in object_list %}
            <p>{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href="/blog/{{post.id}}"> {{ post.title }}</a></p>
            {% endfor %}
        </article>
    </aside>


{% block content %}
{% endblock %}  



    <footer class="mainFooter">
        <p> copyright &copy; 2013</p>
    </footer>

</body>


</html>
```

I also tried putting the .css file and .png file directly into the templates folder where base.html is and then modified the the 2 relevant lines to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>
```

and

```
<img src="mainlogo.png" width="700" height="144">
```

i also tried putting http:// in front of the mainlogo.png ,but I still could not get the image or styles.css to work.

also these errors show up in the cmd.exe window:

```
"GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1646   
"GET /static/img/mainlogo.png HTTP/1.1/" 404 1652
```

Any ideas?  thanks, Tom

simple django project download .zip is located here:

http://pythonprogramming.net/downloads/mysite.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forget to add this line to get the static files :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
```

You are using the development server (`manage.py runserver`) with `DEBUG = True` while having this problem, right?

Because with `DEBUG = False` or in production environment, the static files should be served by your server, or a CDN, or another server : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/deployment/

If none of this is working, check that your static folder is located where it's supposed to : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/ (Configure properly the STATIC_ROOT and django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS or add a static pattern in your ulrpatterns like described in the doc at the link I provided)

Comment: yes i confirmed all of your suggestions. Still going to read more of these docs. thanks, but still .css and .png still not working here.

Comment: i added in the link to zip file of project if have time to look. Thanks http://pythonprogramming.net/downloads/mysite.zip

Comment: I tested with your zip, when I put the absolute path to the static folder (like you did), it works. Check the path you used in the `STATICFiLES_DIRS` setting

Comment: could you tell me exactly what you changed (the line of code to change and an example of the path you used) because i am trying a different combination of options for changing the BASE_DIR and can not get the image or css code to work. (btw when i originally attempted to use an absolute path i did not use the static folder but used the templates folder) thank you

Comment: I changed only in `mysite/mysite/settings.py` the tuple `STATICFILES_DIRS` like this : `STATICFILES_DIR=("C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/mysite/static",)` (because I unzipped your zip on my Desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **{% load staticfiles %}** should 1st string.

```
#example.html
{% load staticfiles %}
.....
```

and collect all staticfiles in project path(where manage.py):

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```